# Feature module providing service

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-module

I seem to understand that if I provide a service in `FeatureModule` then import that module in my `AppModule` (root module), all the providers listed in the feature module become available with application-wide scope.

Yet, this code does not seem to work. Can anyone help me understand what I did wrong?

The feature

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ CommonModule ],
  declarations: [],
  providers: [
    DatetimeService, RandomService
  ]
})
export class FeaturesModule { }
```

The root module

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ AppComponent, ChildComponent ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    FeaturesModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

When I try and inject the `RandomService` in `AppComponent`, it fails miserably like so

```
Error: StaticInjectorError[RandomService]: 
  StaticInjectorError[RandomService]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for RandomService!
    at _NullInjector.get (core.js:923)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1211)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1153)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1024)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1211)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1153)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1024)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10584)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:11805)
    at resolveDep (core.js:12301)
```

I am using the latest Angular 5.

Comment: Actually no, you would have to provide those services in the app level module.

Comment: @OsmanCea that's not true. Providers from all non-lazy loaded modules are available globally.

Comment: @fedmest can you try to reproduce in http://stackblitz.com?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I agree with Günter... I have checked the documentation properly, and I get the feeling that my code *should* provide the service globally...

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer on it! thanks!

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-94rvaj

Comment: I am getting something fundamentally wrong there, I think. I cannot get it to work even without the service injection :-(

Comment: got it! I had a different selector for my app component than the one in the original example...

Comment: Uhmm, besides the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`, which I assume happens because you're calling the `serviceRandom` directly in the template, I don't see how this is broken

Comment: works as expected in stackblitz.com - it's just my local server that doesn't at this point... I will investigate for differences

Comment: @OsmanCea what's that error you mention? I cannot see it anywhere... Am I doing something unconventional by calling the service the way I do?

Comment: Sorry for the late response... it is because you were directly calling a function inside an interpolated expression like this `{{ serviceRandom() }}`, this means that every time Angular triggers change detection it is gonna evaluate that expression and since the function returns a random value, the value of that expression is changing every time Angular checks that template.
You can see the error in your browser developer tools console.